# Serving an image as a tile layer with node mapnik

Tags: mapnik, node-js

I have an image that I get from a server, I need to then take that image and tile it on the fly and pass it back to the user. Everything I see keeps using stylesheets which is not what I want/need. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Your image comes from a webservice? WMS, Geotiff? Others?

Comment: Because if your image is not exotic (special web service), using a tiles server like http://mapproxy.org (Python) avoid any coding...

Comment: My image comes from an analytics server. I wanted to rasterize the image so that 1) I could load huge images to the map, and 2) the images would translate to 3-d as image layers don't go from OL3-> Cesium

Answer (score 1):

For your tile question, look at the right place e.g the [node-mapnik-sample-code repo](https://github.com/mapnik/node-mapnik-sample-code/tree/master/tile)

It's working perfectly with

```
git clone https://github.com/mapnik/node-mapnik-sample-code.git
cd node-mapnik-sample-code
npm install mapnik express generic-pool get
./tile/pool/app.js stylesheet.xml 8000
```

Then, open http://localhost:8000/1/1/1 to see the result!

You can avoid stylesheets with inline stylesheets... if you look at [this sample](https://github.com/mapnik/node-mapnik-sample-code/blob/master/memory_datasource/simple.js) mentioning

> // map with just a style
>
> // eventually the api will support adding styles in javascript

Comment: I really wanted it to create an image pyramid, i.e. slice the tiles up from an image and then serve them as xyz. That doesn't seem doable.

Answer (score 0):

At least figured out how to load an image from a buffer,

```
im = new mapnik.Image.fromBytes(imageFromBuffer)
```

I can't figure out how to then cut that up into a grid or at least give it an extent so that it doesn't repeat the image. That may not be doable.

Edit: The node-mapnik API is abysmally bad. I have found a TON of functions that are in the code that are 1) very useful and 2) completely undocumented. If you run into problems like I did, get the npm, break open the source, and go through it line by line to figure things out.

EDIT 2: Found the real docs, http://mapnik.org/node-mapnik/documentation/# The API from the github/googling is wrong. https://github.com/mapnik/node-mapnik/tree/master/docs , Don't use that.